# Create a .csv file that have two header

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, export-to-csv

I have to create a .csv file that has two headers

example

```
Filename|FileDate|Location|Numberofrows
Testfile|20190101|USA     |1
```

---

```
Firstname|LastName|DOB     |Address1      |Address2
John     |Doe     |20800101|123 4th street|apt 2
```

I just know how to create a CSV file with only one header.
Could anyone tell me how I can create a single .csv file in that format from SQL.

I am using the following method to create a single header csv file

```
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(4000)    
DECLARE @FileDirectory VARCHAR(1000) = 'c:\test\'    
DECLARE @HeaderFile varchar(255) = 'Headers.txt'    
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(255)

SET @FileName = 'TestFile_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)

SET @command = 'bcp "select * from TESTDB.dbo.TEST_Table"'    
       + ' queryout "' + @FileDirectory + @FileName + '.txt"'    
       + ' -c -q -t, -T  -S'+@@servername

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @command

SET @command =  'copy "' + @FileDirectory + @HeaderFile + '"+"' + @FileDirectory + @FileName + '.txt"' +  ' "' + @FileDirectory + @filename + '.csv"'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @command

SET @command = 'del "' + @FileDirectory + @FileName + '.txt"'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @command
```

Comment: i just added on how i create the single header csv file

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

You're already adding one header. Just add another one using the same method.

The dos `COPY` command concatenates files using the `+` operator.

so instead of this:

```
SET @command =  'copy "' + 
    @FileDirectory + @HeaderFile + '"+"' + 
    @FileDirectory + @FileName + '.txt"' +  
    ' "' + @FileDirectory + @filename + '.csv"'
```

Use this:

```
SET @command =  'copy "' + 
    @FileDirectory + @HeaderFile + '"+"' + 
    @FileDirectory + @HeaderFile + '"+"' + 
    @FileDirectory + @FileName + '.txt"' +  
    ' "' + @FileDirectory + @filename + '.csv"'
```

(This is on multiple lines for clarity)

You might need to print the contents of `@command` to debug if you have issues.

It should come out like this:

```
COPY C:\Folder\Header.TXT + C:\Folder\Header.TXT + C:\Folder2\Data.TXT C\OutputFile\FInalFile.CSV
```